# Preventing the link trigger after clicking on the button inside in link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I am using Next JS Link component to go to a specified url but I don't want the Link to be triggered when I click on the button inside the Link
This is my CardItem Component :

```
    <Link href={`/fundraiser/${id}`}>
        <Card className="w-[360px] h-[500px] flex flex-col justify-between">

          <div>
            <CardHeader>
              <CardTitle>{formattedTitle}</CardTitle>
              <CardDescription>{formattedDescription}</CardDescription>
              <CardDescription>{`By ${username}`}</CardDescription>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
              <div>{formattedContent}</div>
            </CardContent>
          </div>

          <div>
            <CardHeader>
              <CardDescription>raised {amountRaised}</CardDescription>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter>
              <Progress className="h-2 " value={value} />
            </CardFooter>
            <CardFooter className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center gap-3">
              {button && (
                <Button className="bg-teal-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md  w-full">
                  Contribute
                </Button>
              )}
              {button && (
               
                  <Dialog>
                    <DialogTrigger  asChild ><Button onClick={handleClick} >Open</Button></DialogTrigger>
                    <DialogContent>
                      <DialogHeader>
                        <DialogTitle>Are you sure absolutely sure?</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogDescription>
                          This action cannot be undone. This will permanently delete your account
                          and remove your data from our servers.
                        </DialogDescription>
                      </DialogHeader>
                    </DialogContent>
                  </Dialog>

                
              )}
            </CardFooter>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </Link>
```

I have tried the `event.stopPropagation()` in the `onClick` on the button inside the DialogTrigger but it didn't work

Is there any way I can do this

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I used preventDefault but I want the dialog to open.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its usually not a good idea to put interactive elements inside interactive elements but you can make a simple function like this

```
  <span onClick={() => handleClick(true, id)}>
      <YourContent />
      <button onClick={(e) => {
          handleLikePost(e);
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}>
        {likes.length}
      </button>
  </span>
```

And your function

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const router = useRouter();
const handleClick = ( boolean, id) => {
    if (condition) {
       router.push(`/fundraiser/${id}`);
    }
  };
```